# Memory leak caused by Logger

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks, classloader

I [read](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.de/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html) that the following code leads to a memory leak as the Level class holds a reference to the CUSTOMLEVEL member from outside the Classloader:

```
public class LeakServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final String STATICNAME = "This leaks!";
  private static final Level CUSTOMLEVEL = new Level("test", 550) {}; // anon class!

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException {
      Logger.getLogger("test").log(CUSTOMLEVEL, "doGet called");
  }
}
```

The question is how is the Level class loaded outside this particular classloader ?
Can I have some other instances within the java API of a similar behaviour?

Comment: "how is the Level class loaded outside this particular classloader ?" - standard classes usually gets loaded using system classloader via hierarchy of classloaders. I am not really sure that there is a leak here, however. Could you provide a reference to the document that tells that there is one?

Comment: Don't bother - found it here: http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html

Comment: [Here](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6543126)

Comment: Yes - i guessed it would be a higher classloader if not the boot classloader.However,are there any other such known API classes which lead to classloader memory leaks that we should be aware of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of sources for class loader leaks:  [This part](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/02/26/classloader-leaks-v-common-mistakes-and-known-offenders/) of a blog series on the issue, enumerates some of the culprits.